# Android Honeycomb: layout problem - hide/show FrameLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

in my `Activity`, I have a layout containing 3 `FrameLayout`s, one at the top, one at the left and one at the "center".

Now, I sometimes only want to display one or two of them. Atm I am doing it this way:

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout_menu_left);
frame.setVisibility(...);

frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout_content);
frame.setVisibility(...);

frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout_menu_top);
frame.setVisibility(...);
```

However this can get really ugly results, e.g. when I switch the "content" `Fragment` and hide the top and/or left `FrameLayout`. It all starts flickering as the "content" `Fragment` jumps to the top and/or left and only afterwards is replaced.

Also, I can obviously not navigate back to another setup, so is there any other way to do this?

Kind regards,
jellyfish

**Edit:**

Maybe a little drawing makes my question clearer...

[image: Layout]

*A* shows a Layout of 3 FrameLayouts containing 3 different Fragments. Each color represents one distinct Fragment.

Now what I want to do is to switch from *A* to *D*.
I am doing this by replacing the blue Fragment with the yellow Fragment via a `FragmentTransaction`.

However, this still keeps the other Frames visible, so I hide them via the code above.

Now, `Frame.setVisibility()` is called way before commit(), so in *B* and *C* the blue Fragment "jumps" to the left and the top and only afterwards (in *D*) is replaced with the yellow Fragment. This produces a nasty flickering.

As a workaround, I now hide all three FrameLayouts before the transaction and re-show the ones I need once the transaction has finished. But there still is the problem that I can't go back via the back button as this isn't a real transaction.

Comment: Are you using fragment transactions? Also, can you elaborate on "and only afterwards is replaced"?

Comment: Hi Roman! Yes I am using Fragment Transactions. I've added some more information, please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have two suggestions.  Firstly, if you both add a fragment transition effect and do the visibility changes after the transaction, that would probably substantially reduce much of your flicker effect

```
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
```

Secondly, I've simply given up on having the system manage the fragment stack for me -- it seems that this only works well with simple transactions.  Override onBackPressed and do your own logic there.

--randy

Comment: Hi randy, thanks for your answer. :) On the first part, I had this idea, too, but got stuck on the "after the transaction" bit. It's really unhandy that after commit() the transaction doesn't take effect immediately. I came up to doing the hiding/showing in the Fragment itself now (where I can be sure the transaction is done). Your second idea sounds great. I didn't run into more problems with the fragment stack management so far, but easily believe you that it doesn't always work 100%. Didn't even think of such a "simple" solution, thanks!

Comment: @jellyfish -- I found out something additional yesterday which might really help -- LayoutTransitions.  This allows you to define a specific animation to occur when a layout changes; you could perhaps use this to add a nice slide-away effect on the transition when views are hidden.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html#layout for documentation -- this could be as simple as a single xml change for you.