# problem in layout display

Tags: android

I am build one app in which two swf are load
    `1st is in background and`
    `2nd is in particular area`
and also one textview & button are included

i want `1st` swf in background and 2nd in front of 1st.

now when i load it i got only 1st swf and 2nd swf while textview and button are not display.

i put code ::

**XML file::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal">
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rela_tranning"
    android:layout_width="480dp" android:layout_height="320dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/trai_bg3">





    <!-- <ImageButton android:id="@+id/tran_btn_exit" android:layout_width="30dp" 
        android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_marginLeft="05dp" android:layout_marginTop="270dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/exit_button"> </ImageButton> -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/trans_linearll" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/tranning_wv_girl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="195dp" android:id="@+id/trans_lin"
        android:layout_height="185dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp" android:layout_marginTop="75dp">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/tranning_wv_main"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- <ImageView android:layout_width="480dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:visibility="invisible" android:id="@+id/tran_imgwv_playnow" /> -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/trans_linearll" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="390dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/tran_btn_skip"
            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="48dp">
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="200dp" android:id="@+id/trans_linearll"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tran_banner"
            android:textSize="19dp" android:textColor="#2557AA" />
        <!-- #FF0000 red color #2557AA for green color -->
    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java file**

```
    package com.adySol;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tranning extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    WebView tranning_wv_main, girl, first_wv;
    boolean flag = false, flag2 = false;


    String first = "file:///android_asset/bike_route_two_h.swf";
    String second = "file:///android_asset/close_two_h.swf";
    String third = "file:///android_asset/exit_two_h.swf";
    String fourth = "file:///android_asset/no_parking _two_h.swf";
    String fifth = "file:///android_asset/one_way_two_h.swf";
    String sixth = "file:///android_asset/phone_two_h.swf";
    String seventh = "file:///android_asset/rail_crossing_two_h.swf";
    String eighth = "file:///android_asset/sale_two_h.swf";
    String nineth = "file:///android_asset/stop_two_h.swf";
    String tenth = "file:///android_asset/turn_off_the_tap_two_h.swf";
    Typeface face;
    String background = "file:///android_asset/screen2.swf";
    private MediaPlayer xmPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer(),
            xmPlayer3 = new MediaPlayer(), xmPlayer4 = new MediaPlayer(),
            xmPlayer5 = new MediaPlayer(), xmPlayer6 = new MediaPlayer(),
            xmPlayer7 = new MediaPlayer(), xmPlayer8 = new MediaPlayer(),
            xmPlayer9 = new MediaPlayer(), xmPlayer10 = new MediaPlayer(),
            xmPlayer11 = new MediaPlayer();
    CountDownTimer aCounter, aCounter2, aCounter3, aCounter4, aCounter5,
            aCounter6, aCounter7, aCounter8, aCounter9, aCounter10, aCounter11;
    Intent touchAndShow;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tranning);

        face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/comic.TTF");

        ImageButton tran_btn_skip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tran_btn_skip);
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                    "http://203.109.115.55/MRESC/images/test/skip.png")
                    .getContent());
            tran_btn_skip.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        touchAndShow = new Intent(this, TouchandShow.class);
        tran_btn_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    flag = true;
                    /*
                     * xmPlayer2.stop(); xmPlayer3.stop(); xmPlayer4.stop();
                     * xmPlayer5.stop(); xmPlayer6.stop(); xmPlayer7.stop();
                     * xmPlayer8.stop(); xmPlayer9.stop(); xmPlayer10.stop();
                     * xmPlayer11.stop();
                     */
                    startActivity(touchAndShow);
                    touchAndShow.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });

        final TextView tran_banner;
        tran_banner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tran_banner);
        tran_banner.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);

        girl = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tranning_wv_girl);
        girl.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        girl.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        girl.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        girl.loadUrl(background);

        aCounter = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tran_banner.setText("Route Sign");
                swfLoad(first, xmPlayer2, "bike_route.mp3", "Route Sign");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                aCounter2 = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        tran_banner.setText("Closed Sign");
                        swfLoad(second, xmPlayer3, "closed.mp3", "Closed Sign");
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {

                        aCounter3 = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                tran_banner.setText("Exit Sign");
                                swfLoad(third, xmPlayer4, "exit.mp3",
                                        "Exit Sign");
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                                aCounter4 = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        tran_banner.setText("No Parking Sign");
                                        swfLoad(fourth, xmPlayer5,
                                                "no_parking.mp3",
                                                "No Parking Sign");
                                    }

                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        aCounter5 = new CountDownTimer(4000,
                                                1000) {
                                            public void onTick(
                                                    long millisUntilFinished) {

                                                swfLoad(fifth, xmPlayer6,
                                                        "one_way.mp3",
                                                        "One Way Sign");
                                            }

                                            public void onFinish() {
                                                aCounter6 = new CountDownTimer(
                                                        4000, 1000) {
                                                    public void onTick(
                                                            long millisUntilFinished) {

                                                        swfLoad(sixth,
                                                                xmPlayer7,
                                                                "phone.mp3",
                                                                "Phone Sign");
                                                    }

                                                    public void onFinish() {
                                                        aCounter7 = new CountDownTimer(
                                                                4000, 1000) {
                                                            public void onTick(
                                                                    long millisUntilFinished) {
                                                                swfLoad(seventh,
                                                                        xmPlayer8,
                                                                        "rail_cross_wav.wav",
                                                                        "Rail Crossing Sign");
                                                            }

                                                            public void onFinish() {
                                                                aCounter8 = new CountDownTimer(
                                                                        5000,
                                                                        1000) {
                                                                    public void onTick(
                                                                            long millisUntilFinished) {
                                                                        swfLoad(eighth,
                                                                                xmPlayer9,
                                                                                "sale.mp3",
                                                                                "Sale Sign");
                                                                    }

                                                                    public void onFinish() {
                                                                        aCounter9 = new CountDownTimer(
                                                                                4000,
                                                                                1000) {
                                                                            public void onTick(
                                                                                    long millisUntilFinished) {
                                                                                swfLoad(nineth,
                                                                                        xmPlayer10,
                                                                                        "stop.mp3",
                                                                                        "Stop Sign");

                                                                            }

                                                                            public void onFinish() {
                                                                                aCounter10 = new CountDownTimer(
                                                                                        4000,
                                                                                        1000) {
                                                                                    public void onTick(
                                                                                            long millisUntilFinished) {
                                                                                        swfLoad(tenth,
                                                                                                xmPlayer11,
                                                                                                "turn_off_tap.mp3",
                                                                                                "Turn off Tap Sign");

                                                                                    }

                                                                                    public void onFinish() {
                                                                                        flag2 = true;
                                                                                        first_wv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                                                                        aCounter11 = new CountDownTimer(
                                                                                                4000,
                                                                                                1000) {
                                                                                            public void onTick(
                                                                                                    long millisUntilFinished) {
                                                                                                flag2 = true;
                                                                                                // invisibleControl();
                                                                                            }

                                                                                            public void onFinish() {
                                                                                                startActivity(touchAndShow);
                                                                                                touchAndShow
                                                                                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                                                                                finish();

                                                                                            }
                                                                                        };
                                                                                        aCounter11
                                                                                                .start();

                                                                                    }
                                                                                };
                                                                                aCounter10
                                                                                        .start();
                                                                            }
                                                                        };
                                                                        aCounter9
                                                                                .start();
                                                                    }
                                                                };
                                                                aCounter8
                                                                        .start();
                                                            }
                                                        };
                                                        aCounter7.start();
                                                    }
                                                };
                                                aCounter6.start();
                                            }
                                        };
                                        aCounter5.start();
                                    }
                                };
                                aCounter4.start();
                            }
                        };
                        aCounter3.start();
                    }
                };
                aCounter2.start();
            }
        };
        aCounter.start();

        /*
         * WebView third_wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tranning_wv_main);
         * third_wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         * third_wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
         * third_wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
         * third_wv.loadUrl(third);
         */
    }

    public void swfLoad(String xurl, final MediaPlayer player,
            final String music1, final String banner) {
        if (flag == false) {

            first_wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tranning_wv_main);
            first_wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            first_wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            first_wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            if (flag2 == true) {

                first_wv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                first_wv.loadUrl(xurl);
            }
            try {
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setDataSource("http://203.109.115.55/MRESC/images/test/"
                        + music1);
                player.prepare();
                player.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        } else if (flag == true) {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use FrameLayout to resolve your problem, and not LinearLayout !
Check out this post : 
[Android Honeycomb: layout problem - hide/show FrameLayouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373631/android-honeycomb-layout-problem-hide-show-framelayouts)

Hope it helps you